# bash sed removing port numbers in log

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to do a sort|uniq on a log file to get a better understanding of the log entries..
In doing so, I would like to remove the port numbers from a certain pattern.

```
Sep 11 21:31:47 apple.net RT_FLOW: RT_FLOW_SESSION_DENY: session denied 12.34.56.11/234->56.67.89.12/9292 icmp 1(8) default-deny applelan External UNKNOWN UNKNOWN N/A(N/A) vlan.202 UNKNOWN policy deny
```

I have the following line to remove the first port number from the first IP address.

```
sed -i 's/\/.*\->/\->/g' $TMP_FILE
```

leaving me with `12.34.56.11->56.67.89.12/9292`

I would like to get it to `12.34.56.11->56.67.89.12` instead.
I tried

```
sed -i 's/\/.*\''/''/g' $TMP_FILE
```

but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mention  `''`

```
sed -i 's/\/.*//g' $TMP_FILE
```

or

A single sed code will do this job for you.

```
sed -i 's~/[[:digit:]]\+~~g' file
```

Since you want to match `/`, you may change the sed delimiters. Here I used `~` as delimiter instead of forward slashes. So `/` matches a literal `/` symbol and the POSIX class `[[:digit:]]\+` will match one or more digit characters. Replacing those matched chars with an empty string will give you the desired output.

Example:

```
$ echo '12.34.56.11/234->56.67.89.12/9292' | sed 's~/[[:digit:]]\+~~g'
12.34.56.11->56.67.89.12
```

Comment: `sed -i 's~/[[:digit:]]\+~~g' file`

Works perfectly!
Would you mind explaining how this sed command works?

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -`Eo` you can get this:

```
grep -Eo '[.0-9/]+->[.0-9/]+' file
12.34.56.11/234->56.67.89.12/9292
```

Now pipe this result with `sed` to get rid of number after `/`:

```
grep -Eo '[.0-9/]+->[.0-9/]+' file | sed 's~/[0-9]*~~g'
12.34.56.11->56.67.89.12
```